# import discord SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: discord.py

Trying to run a script within linux, using Python3 (most recent), upon trying to load the script with my bot, I get 'import discord' with an arrow pointing at import saying 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax' [Visual of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfpHY.png) -- cant post pictures yet.

Code Block: `import discord import subprocess from pathlib import Path`

Answer (score 0):

To import library, you do it in the beginning. Then you can start initializing any variable you need. So first what you would want to do:

```
import discord
BOT_TOKEN = "YOUR_TOKEN"
```

Here is a resource you might want to read.
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html